# How to add a user in page role in Facebook page via API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-permissions

I have checked [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/roles/) which clearly states that creating,updating and deleting is not allowed on that end point(page roles end point).

If that is so, how is Mailchimp is able to do so. If you look into image below, it adds an advertiser role when I try to create ad from their platform.
[mailchimp added advertiser role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PSpH.png)

So my question is, if documentation states it's not possible, how did Mailchimp add that role in my page? It is a page role right? 
Anyone knows the alternative way of getting this done?

Thank you,